# Node.js mysql query is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm running the following code on `Node.js`  and
I am trying to use `mysql` with `nodejs`: trying to run the query: `select numbers from TABLE`. The result comes out as:

> "undefined"

```
function getNumbers()
{
    cio.query("SELECT numbers FROM rooms WHERE durum='1'", function(err, result)
    {
        if (err) 
         throw err;
        else
     result[0].numbers;

    });

}
var kar = getNumbers();
 console.log(kar);
```

So, what should I do ? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions `getNumbers()` and the function called inside it don't return any values, so the result will **always** be `undefined`.

Other than that you need to handle the [**asynchronous**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous) nature of the function:
**wait until the database query is complete before returning a value**.
You can do this by using a [**callback function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Example below:

```
function getNumbers(callback) {
    cio.query("SELECT numbers FROM rooms WHERE durum='1'", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback((result.length > 0) ? result[0].numbers : "");
    });
}

getNumbers(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... I tried but I get the "undefined" error again ... :(

Comment: The function `getNumbers` and the function inside it should **both** return a value. I've included an example in my answer.

Comment: You can't synchronously return an asynchronous method, look at marked dupe.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: this time I'm getting a different erro. I'm very sorry. 
 " _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT numbers FROM rooms WHERE durum=\'1\'',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection:
   Connection {
     _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Array] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     config:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: 'localhost',

Comment: Can you share the code you used that produced that error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question depends on your `console.log` but your function has no return value. So when you have no return then it's `undefined`.

```
function getNumbers() {
    return 'test';
}
var kar = getNumbers();
console.log(kar);
```